# ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION returning duplicate values

Tags: sql-server-2008, row-number

The following query results in duplicate row_numbers after the first partitioned set. For example, the first set of fldPK = 2403 and fldCIA = 1 I receive the following...

```
2403    1    1
2403    1    2
2403    1    3
2403    1    4
```

and in the second set I receive...

```
2403    2    1
2403    2    1 <-- duplicate 1 within the same partition
2403    2    2
2403    2    3

    SELECT *, 1 AS fldBF, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fldPK, fldCIA ORDER BY fldPK) AS sCount 
    INTO #tmpTable 
    FROM V_qryCSPGA 
    WHERE fldPK IN(SELECT DISTINCT thePK FROM FN_qryAllDTPK()) 

    UNION ALL   

    SELECT *, 1 AS fldBF, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fldPK, fldCIA ORDER BY fldPK) AS sCount 
    FROM FN_qryCSGBA() 
    WHERE fldPK IN(SELECT DISTINCT thePK FROM FN_qryAllDTPK())
    ORDER BY fldPK, fldCIA, fldNDat;
```

Why is this occurring? for every set of fldPK and fldCIA I need a to restart the row number count at 1, more proper data would be...

```
2403    3    1
2403    3    2
2403    3    3
2403    3    4
2403    3    5
2403    3    6
2403    3    7
2403    3    8
2403    3    9
```

Comment: You have a `UNION`, thats' why. Two separate countings.

Comment: Kinda figured, is there anyway to do an update if I initially create a NULL sCount column? I tried it but all of the sCount values were 1.

Comment: You could UNION in a derived table, then ROW_NUMBER() in the external query. That will give different numbers to the rows that get duplicates now (if that's what you need.)

Comment: Do the rows from the first part of the Union need to get the low numbers and the rows from the 2nd part the high numbers?

Comment: no, i'm basically just joining the tables with the union and then partitioning from there and inserting the row number for however many points there are for each fldPK and fldCIA pair.

Comment: @ypercube I added another example of proper data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will stop the duplicate numbers. Whether the new numbering will be what you are really after, is another thing:

```
; WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT *, 1 AS fldBF
    FROM V_qryCSPGA 
    WHERE fldPK IN(SELECT DISTINCT thePK FROM FN_qryAllDTPK()) 

    UNION ALL   

    SELECT *, 1 AS fldBF
    FROM FN_qryCSGBA() 
    WHERE fldPK IN(SELECT DISTINCT thePK FROM FN_qryAllDTPK())
  )
SELECT *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fldPK, fldCIA ORDER BY fldPK) AS sCount 
INTO #tmpTable 
FROM cte 
ORDER BY fldPK, fldCIA, fldNDat;
```